# How to remove and update table field data on occurrence of specific string?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update the table by removing some text in the table.
For example,

Table field data is:
"I Like Trees",
"I Like Fruits",
"I Like Songs"

I want to make it as on occurrence of Like I want to remove all after with "Like",
Output should be as,
"I ",
"I ",
"I "

Any help, please?

Comment: if you want just **i** then `update table_name set comment = "i"`.this will also work to remove string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Update table
set col = SUBSTRING(col,1,CHARINDEX('LIKE',col,0)-1)
where column like '%Like%'
```

Comment: Or give as much as the detail of that column info so that I could modify to a more general answer

Comment: No, Sorry but it was a just example string may vary, I want to remove and update all the data after a specific string.

Comment: Update table
set col = SUBSTRING(col,1,CHARINDEX('LIKE',col,0)-1)
where column like '%Like%'

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
UPDATE MyTable
set MyField = substring(MyField, 1, INSTR(MyField, 'Like')-1)
where MyField like '%Like%'
```